# elseif does not work

Tags: php, if-statement, is-empty

This should be quite simple, but for some reason it does not work. Can you point to something?

```
if ( !empty( $data[$i][19] )) {
    $an_image = "<img src='/images/camera.gif' title='Der er et billede' />";
} elseif( !empty( $data[$i][24] )) {
    $an_image = "<img src='/images/camera.gif' title='Der er et billede' />";
} elseif( !empty( $data[$i][25] )) {
    $an_image = "<img src='/images/camera.gif' title='Der er et billede' />";
} else {
    $an_image = "";
}
```

It should simply check three variables from data, and return an icon if there is something in any of them.

Comment: How exactly does it not work ? What happens ?

Comment: Have you `var_dump()`'ed `$data[$i]` to ensure that it *has* the content?

Comment: This code seems to be inside of a loop, please provide more code to recive a better answer.

Comment: posting the result of `var_dump($data[$i])` would help better

Comment: May be `$data[$i][19]` is always not empty that's why its not going to elseif condition?.

Comment: On a side note, what's wrong with ``if (!empty(...[19]) || !empty(...[24]) || !empty(...[25])) {...} else {...} `` ... there really doesn't seem to be a reason for duplicating the code three times.

Comment: Please define "does not work". Maybe show more code. But you should certainly improve your question. Imagine someone coming to you with this same question.

Comment: Oh my god!! - i am so sorry guys. The error was (as you suspected) in the variable...

Im sorry to have wasted your time here. I have another mysql query running for this loop. I got confused here... It works as intented :)

Comment: @MortenHansen You could still think about the code futuregeek posted - it is a much cleaner version of achieving the same.

Comment: That, and also the one Moritz posted. I actually started out with that one, but in my futile attempt to solve the problem by trying another approach, i ended up with "elseif". But yes, simpler is ALWAYS better.  And the variables were actually empty, so both worked as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply use the or operator?

```
if ( $x || $y || $z ){
    $an_image = "<img src='/images/camera.gif' title='Der er et billede' />";
} else {
    $an_image = "";
}
```

http://codepad.org/zeyPPLYP

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array(array(19, 24, 25), $data[$i]))
{
     $an_image = "<img src='/images/camera.gif' title='Der er et billede' />";

}
else
{
     $an_image = "";
}
```

Check if that works.

Comment: I guess the problem is the loop that generates `$i`, but this is a much cleaner approach for sure. The loop runs for x times, and only the last result is stored in `$an_image`, I guess.

Comment: I think he wants different images depending upon the value.

Comment: @Sabin OP said "and return an icon if there is something in any of them", so I guess he need an image when condition matches, else nothing.